# 'Buffered' function for Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

My application has a whole chain of Observables running through it, and recently I found that something was slowing down my (hot) source, but I couldn't work out where.

Obviously, with everything running in series by default, a good first step was to introduce some 'parallelism', so after having done battle with my own implementation, I discovered that `ObserveOn` did what I wanted: allow a source to 'carry on' while a subscriber did whatever.

But that didn't solve my problem of knowing where the slow bits were. Which lead me to trying to invent a `Buffered` function which does the buffering, but also tells me how long the buffer is.

I'm aware that this doesn't do all the fancy Rx business of giving you the choice of which scheduler and all that, but for my purposes currently Task is good enough (unless you tell me otherwise):

This is the tuple used to return data in:

```
public class WithBufferSize<T>
{
    public readonly T Value;
    public readonly int BufferSize;
    public WithBufferSize(T value, int bufferSize)
    {
        Value = value;
        BufferSize = bufferSize;
    }
}
```

Here is the function:

```
public static IObservable<WithBufferSize<T>> Buffered<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<WithBufferSize<T>>(observer =>
    {
        var buffer = new BlockingCollection<T>();
        Exception exception = null;
        bool completed = false;
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            foreach(var t in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                observer.OnNext(new WithBufferSize<T>(t, buffer.Count));
            if(exception != null) 
                observer.OnError(exception);
            else if(completed) 
                observer.OnCompleted();
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        task.Start();
        var subscription = source.Subscribe(t => buffer.Add(t),
        ex =>
        {
            exception = ex;
            buffer.CompleteAdding();
        },
        () =>
        {
            completed = true;
            buffer.CompleteAdding();
        });
        return new CompositeDisposable(
            subscription, 
            Disposable.Create(() => buffer.CompleteAdding()));
    }).Publish().RefCount();
}
```

I originally used `Materialise`, but switched to using flags because it creates less objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix tasks scheduling with rx. Instead use the `IScheduler` interface. You can request a scheduler as an input parameter, and also provide an overload with a default scheduler.

```
public static IObservable<WithBufferSize<T>> Buffered<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IScheduler scheduler) {
    ...
    var task =  scheduler.Schedule(() =>
    ...
}
```

That brings me to your use of `BlockingCollection`. This will block your current thread, and means every subscription will consume an additional thread. That can get costly. Might be better to replace it with scheduling or async/await.

You also use `.Publish().RefCount()` later on, remember that the resulting observable will only be hot if you reuse that observable, if you call `Buffered` again, it will create a new observable, with it's own call to `Publish()`. Also I find it poor practice to hide `Publish().RefCount()` inside an extension method, it can have unexpected effects if you are not aware of it. If you really need `Publish().RefCount()` in other locations, use it there.

In Rx, when dispose is called, you should attempt to stop all outstanding work. `task` is disposable, so you can freely pass it to the `CompositeDisposable`. It is worth noting that when you dispose the outer observable, `observer.OnNext` becomes a no-op, so the task will already be ending fairly quickly anyway.

Now, I could rewrite your code and apply all suggested fixes. Instead, I'm going to show you how to write the same using `Interlocked`.

```
public static IObservable<WithBufferSize<T>> Buffered<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return source.Buffered(Scheduler.Default);
}

public static IObservable<WithBufferSize<T>> Buffered<T>(this IObservable<T> source, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<WithBufferSize<T>>(ob =>
    {
        int count = 0;
        return source
            .Do(_ => Interlocked.Increment(ref count))
            .ObserveOn(scheduler)
            .Select(item => new WithBufferSize<T>(item, Interlocked.Decrement(ref count)))
            .Subscribe(ob);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give your suggestion a try. While you're here, do you have any ideas on how to unit test this kind of thing? I've had terrible difficulty.

Comment: That's why we're passing the `IScheduler` interface around. You can pass the `TestScheduler` to Buffered. Use the test schedulers sleep function inside the subscribtion and advance functions to push forwards time and let the generator (that also operate on the test scheduler) generate messages. There are various [online resources](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html) that show how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

Don't expose fields, even if they're `readonly`:

```
public readonly T Value;
public readonly int BufferSize;
```

Instead expose properties:

```
public T Value { get; private set; }
public int BufferSize { get; private set; }
```